# Problem: IBM BPM version 8.6.0. Doesn't inserted new rows to BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB table

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm

Problem: IBM BPM version 8.6.0. BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB table doesn't updated (Doesn't inserted new rows to this table it's about 2 months or more). That cause frequently down of BPM Application.

What can be a problem? Can anyone give some fix decision or recommendations ?